# Change Controller Route in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

So I have a `HomeController`, to access it along with `Actions` I have to type *url.com/home/action*.

Would it be possible to change this to something else like *url.com/anothernamethatpointstohomeactually/action*?

Answer (score 57):

I suggest you to use attribute routing, but of course it depends on your scenario.

```
[Route("prefix")]
public class Home : Controller {

    [HttpGet("name")]
    public IActionResult Index() {
    }

}
```

This will be found at `url.com/prefix/name`

There are a lot of options to attribute routing, some samples:

```
[Route("[controller]")] // there are placeholders for common patterns 
                           as [area], [controller], [action], etc.

[HttpGet("")] // empty is valid. url.com/prefix

[Route("")] // empty is valid. url.com/

[HttpGet("/otherprefix/name")] // starting with / won't use the route prefix

[HttpGet("name/{id}")]
public IActionResult Index(int id){ ... // id will bind from route param.

[HttpGet("{id:int:required}")] // you can add some simple matching rules too.
```

Check [Attribute Routing official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

Answer (score 3):

You can add new `Routes` in your `Startup.Configure` method within your `app.UseMvc(routes =>` block:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "SomeDescriptiveName",                      
    template: "AnotherNameThatPointsToHome/{action=Index}/{id?}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home"} 
);
```

The code is quite similar to ASP.NET MVC.

For more info, see [Routing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing).

**Below is for ASP.NET MVC (not ASP.NET Core MVC)**

You can also add a new `Route` via `routes.MapRoute` in your `RouteConfig`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "SomeDescriptiveName",
    url: "AnotherNameThatPointsToHome/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Make sure, you insert the code before you define your `Default` route.

For more information, visit the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs).

Comment: In .net core 3.1. you need to use app.useEndPoints();

Answer (score 3):

In ASP.NET Core 6, we just do that in one line.

Go to your Controller and write before your action method:

```
[Route("YourController/YourAction/{YourParameter?}")]
```

In your example, you you need to write like this:

```
[Route("Home/Index/{name?}")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the Route attribute on top of your controller will allow you to define the route on the entire controller.
`[Route("anothernamethatpointstohomeactually")]`

You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing).

Answer (score -1):

You can change your url by modifying your routing configuration.
It is kind of like htaccess but not really.
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs](http://MS%20Routing)

Another solution is to create a page and do a server redirect.

```
Server.Transfer
```

Comment: Server.Transfer does not exist in asp.net core mvc.

Comment: Your link seems to be broken.