# Issue with a href link

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco

I know it might look like a silly question but I am asking after spending a lot of time to figure it out.

I am trying to figure out from where the following link opening a window to download files

```
<h3>@Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("ProductsPage_Download_CadDownload_Text", "CAD Downloads")</h3>
                                        <a id="downloadcad" class="blue-btn icon-btn disabled" href="/cad-download" data-requestaction="down" target="_self"><i class="download cad"></i>@Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("ProductsPage_Download_CadDownload_Link_Text", "Download CAD File")</a>
```

It seems like a simple link in a .cshtml page that is opening a "/cad-download" page/window. But the problem is there is no cad-download page/route/window or anything in project that I have but it work fine.

Any ideas would be really appreciated!

Comment: Did you check your controllers?

Comment: Yes I did, there is nothing with this name or route

Comment: How did you do the research? With CTRL+F on the full project? Be aware that part of the route may be replaced and the route wouldn't be fully written in any of your files.

Comment: Yes, used CTRL+F with current project and entire solution search options. Couldn't find any reference to this route. I think even if it is being replaced, shouldn't we still have this route name with new route name somewhere in the code? One thing I want to mention, this link is opening a new window and that window has a page from another application to download some files. So the page that is actually doing the download is in another application and this link is just opening a window with that page inside it.

Comment: Not necessarily, as I said it could be part of it: ex: `cad-[controller]`. You have several possibilities: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45806238/change-controller-route-in-asp-net-core

Answer (score 0):

The A tag has an ID and a data attribute, and the URL doesn't contain an identifier. It looks like the link is being handled with JavaScript.

Search for references to the ID `downloadcad` or the data attribute `requestaction` and value `down` in the JavaScript included in the page and I expect you'll find the code that makes the download work.